# I have two errors everytime I do fetch "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')" and "Unhandled Runtime Error"

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, fetch, next.js13

I'm tryin to learn nextjs and I was building a page and everything was working normal until i tried to deploy the app. I have some fetch's that are not working anymore and I've been trying to figure it out what is the issue and I found that the page renders more than it should be and I thinks that is why fetch's are broken. I hope anyone can take a look and help me with this.

`"use client"
import CarRentalMain from "@/components/CarRentalMain/CarRentalMain";
import { useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";

const CarsAvailablePage = async () => {
const searchParams = useSearchParams()

```
const params = {
    pickupLocation: searchParams.get('pickupLocation'),
    dropoffLocation : searchParams.get('dropoffLocation'),
    pickupDate: searchParams.get('pickupDate'),
    dropoffDate : searchParams.get('dropoffDate'),
    pickupTime: searchParams.get('pikcupTime'),
    dropoffTime : searchParams.get('dropoffTime')
}

const data = await getData(params.pickupLocation);

return (
    <>
      <CarRentalMain 
      cars={data}
      rentalDetails={params}
      />
   </>
```

)
};

export default CarsAvailablePage;

export async function getData(location) {

```
const res = await fetch('https://car-rental-7e85a-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/cars.json', { next: { revalidate:  60 } })
// The return value is *not* serialized
// You can return Date, Map, Set, etc.

// Recommendation: handle errors
if (!res.ok) {
    // This will activate the closest `error.js` Error Boundary
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch data')
}

if(location) {
    const data = await res.json();

    const availableCars = data.filter(car => car.availability[location] === true);

    return availableCars;
} else {
    return res.json();
}
```

}
`

I've tried to change the revalidate time and also tried to set the cache to no-store but it didnt worked out. The problem now is that that page is not working now when it did before.